# Gaussian approximation integrated over a unit square, written in terms of error function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, probability, integration, error-analysis

So I am new here, and I apologize for my last question being badly formatted with too much extra information making it just painful to read. I am struggling with getting down a 2D Gaussian estimation integral and I would really appreciate help or pointers to where this topic is covered such that I can translate it in terms of $\operatorname{erf}()$.

Basically, given the 2D Gaussian function,
$$PSF(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 π σ^2} \exp\left[\frac{-(x - θ_x)^2 - (y - θ_y)^2}{2 σ^2}\right],$$ where $θ_{x,y}$ is the center of the Gaussian and $A_k$ is the area over a unit square centered on $(x,y)$. I am trying to show

\begin{align}
\int_{A_k} [PSF(u,v) \mathrm{d}u \mathrm{d}v] &=
\left[\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x - θ_x + \frac{1}{2}}{2 σ^2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x - θ_x - \frac{1}{2}}{2 σ^2}\right) \right] \\
 &\quad\times\left[ \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y - θ_y + \frac{1}{2}}{2 σ^2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{y - θ_y - \frac{1}{2}}{2 σ^2}\right)\right]
\end{align}

I have been trying to tackle this for the last few hours, but I have not been successful. As I said, I would appreciate any and all pointers that might help with me figuring out what step I am mishandling or not understanding.

Comment: What part of the integral are you having troubles on?

Comment: What does this have to do physics and have you heard of Fubini's [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)?

Comment: I think I'm struggling to understand a conversion to erf() that results in the same parameters; also I'll look back over Fubini's theorem, thanks for the link! -- As for what it has to do with physics; the original question was posted on math.SE but they suggested it'd be better here, but I think that's because the context is photon detection over a pixel unit area.

Comment: What do you mean "conversion to erf"? The finite integral over a gaussian *is* the very definition *of* the error function! It might be beneficial to include your work in the post itself, though this is likely failing the homework policy here.